# Get List of users who viewed blog in liferay

Tags: liferay

I want the list of users who viewed blog in liferay  . I am able to get no of views from AssetEntry table . but I want list of users who visited  the blog . 
Is there any solution for that problem ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct solution/configuration for your requirement.

One solution:

You may override struts-action(/blogs/view_entry) using plugin-hook.

In your custom struts-action class, you can store user detail with blog-id in custom database table(using service builder).
Later, you can fetch user detail who viewed blog using service API.